# Is there a special name for matrices with $M[j,i] = M[i,i] - k, i \neq j$?

Tags: matrices, reference-request, terminology

**Backgroud:**

I am working on a computer science problem and arrives at a matrix $M$ with the following property:

> - The size of Matrix $M$ is $n\times n$.
> - For each row $j$, we have $M[j,i] = M[i,i] - k$, for each $i \neq j$, where $k$ is a fixed constant.

For example, $M$ can be (the constant $k = 3$ here):
$$
\mathbf{M} = \left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
5 & 12 & 1 & 6 & 7 \\
2 & 15 & 1 & 6 & 7 \\
2 & 12 & 4 & 6 & 7 \\
2 & 12 & 1 & 9 & 7 \\
2 & 12 & 1 & 6 & 10
\end{array} \right)
$$

**Problem: Is there some special name for such matrices? What are the properties (in terms of matrix theory) of such matrices?**

Comment: I don't see how your matrix is a special case of this. It seems that each row should have constant entries, save the diagonal entry.

Comment: $M_{ij}=c_j+k\ \delta_{ij}$

Comment: In other words, $M = k I + e v^T$ where $e$ is the $n$-component column vector of all $1$'s, and $v$ is some
$n$-component column vector.

Comment: @AlexYoucis The example matrix may be misleading. I have modified it.

Comment: @RobertIsrael The example matrix is misleading. The diagonal entries can be arbitrary. However, once they are fixed, the matrix is fixed according to the $M[j,i] = M[i,i] - k$ property. Thanks.

Comment: ... which says exactly that $M = kI - e v^T$.